# Error check (files)

Tags: c

How can I implement an error check that will loop until a code within a file is entered? This is what I have so far: I have already store each code from the file in an array called `array[j].code1`.

```
Here:  
printf("Enter item code: ");                                        //Prompts user
scanf ("%14s", codenew1);                                           //Read user input
len = strlen(codenew1);                                             //Read each character into variable len

while (len != strspn(codenew1, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
{
    printf ("Name contains non-alphabet characters. Try again!: "); //Prompts user to try again
    scanf ("%14s", codenew1);                                       //Reads user input
    len = strlen(codenew1);                                         //Read each character into variable len
}                                                                   //Endwhile
strncpy(codenew, codenew1,2);                                       //Copy the first two characters from the variable codenew1
codenew[2] = 0;                                                     //Store first two characters into variavle codenew

for ( j = 0; j < num_items; j++)                                    //Loop for num_items times
{                                                                   //Beginning of for loop
    if (strcmp(array[j].code1, codenew) == 0)                       //If codenew is found in file
    {                                                               //Beginning of if statement
        price[i] = item_qty[i] * array[j].price1;                   //Calculating the price of an item
        printf("Price : %d", price[i]);                             //Prints price
        printf("\nEnter '%s' to confirm: ", array[j].itemname1);    //Confirming the item
        scanf("%19s", item_name1[i]);
        while (strcmp(item_name1[i], array[j].itemname1 )!=0)       //Looping until both item names are the same
        {                                                           //Begin while loop
            printf("Item name is not %s ,Try Again!: ", array[j].itemname1);    //Prompt user to try again
            scanf ("%19s", item_name1[i]);                              //Reads item name into an array
            len = strlen(item_name1[i]);                                //Reads each character into variable len
        }                                                               //End while loop
        len = strlen(item_name1[i]);                                    //Read each character into variable len
        while (len != strspn(item_name1[i], "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))    //While len contains non alphabetic characters
        {                                                                       //Beginning while
            printf ("Name contains non-alphabet characters. Try again!: ");     //Prompts user to try again
            scanf ("%19s", item_name1[i]);                                      //Read user input
            len = strlen(item_name1[i]);                                        //Read each character into variable len
        }                                                                       //End while
        strncpy(item_name[i], item_name1[i], 20);                               //Copy the first two characters from the variable codenew1
        item_name[i][20] = 0;                                                   //Store first 20 characters in variable item_name[i]
        total_price+= price[i];                                     //Calculate total price
        break;                                                      //Terminates loop
    }                                                               //End of if statement
    else 
        if (strcmp(array[j].code1, codenew) != 0)                       //If codenew is found in file
        {
            printf("Invalid input! Try again.");
            goto Here;
        }
}                                                           //End of for loop
```

Comment: I would put all of that code into a function. The function should return a boolean that indicates success or failure. Keep calling the function until it returns success.

Comment: All your comments are redundant and should not be there. Although that doesn't mean you shouldn't have any comments.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you show me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

The current structure of the code is

```
Here:

// get "codenew" from user

for ( j = 0; j < num_items; j++ )
{
    if ( strcmp(array[j].code1, codenew) == 0) )
    {
        // do a whole bunch of stuff

        break;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(array[j].code1, codenew != 0) )
    {
        printf( "Invalid input! Try again.\n" );

        goto Here;
    }
}
```

The behavior of the code is to check the first entry in a list of codes. If the first entry matches the user input, then "whole bunch of stuff" gets executed and the loop breaks. Otherwise, an error message gets printed and the code jumps back to the label `Here:`. Thus, the user is forced to enter the first code in the list. Any other code just jumps back to the beginning.

I assume that what the code should do is scan the whole list to see if it can find a matching entry. To accomplish that, I would put the code into a subroutine that searches the list and returns `1` if it finds a match, or `0` if no match is found. The function would be called repeatedly until the user enters a valid code. Here's the structure of the proposed function.

```
int findCode( void )
{
    // get "codenew" from user

    for ( j = 0; j < num_items; j++ )
    {
        if ( strcmp(array[j].code1, codenew) == 0) )
        {
            // do a whole bunch of stuff

            return 1;   // SUCCESS, the user entered a valid code
        }
    }

    return 0;   // FAILED, no matching code in the list
}
```

Here's how the function would be called. The `while` loop will keep calling the function until it returns "success".

```
while ( !findCode() )
    printf( "Invalid input! Try again.\n" );
```